# How do I build my own home network?

Tags: 10.10, windows, networking

I'd like to have my own Ubuntu-based home network. That means, that I can access all my multimedia files from each computer.

1. Music/Files/Videos are on Ubuntu 10.10.
2. I'd like to have access to these files from Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.10.
3. I'd like to have full permissions/privileges.

What's the easiest to get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a good community guide to setup your file sharing network ( Ubuntu to Ubuntu and even Ubuntu to Windows )

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/internet/C/networking-shares.html

Also if you want to setup a UPNP Media Server ( to play videos/music/pictures in streaming from the server ) you can look at:

MediaTomb: http://mediatomb.cc/
( with Installation and configuration guide 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MediaTomb )

Or if you're interested in PS3 streaming ( and similar devices )

PS3 Media Server: http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/